# How to activate v-sync with nvidia linux driver?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Hello I have archlinux with xfce4 installed and I'm wondering how to activate v-sync cause when I move windows around it's tearing up and disgusting. I augmented the refresh rate to 144hz and it corrected the problem a bit but I still wish to be able to activate V-sync or even better G-sync (got compatible monitor) if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of the NVIDIA driver have `SyncToVBlank` enabled by default, and the latest long-lived driver seems to remove this option completely.

If you're using a composite manager, that's a good place to look for additional sync settings.  ArchWiki has a [good resource for setting up Compton](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compton) which has a `--vsync` flag.